# Why does proguard require you to add both -keep and -dontwarn?

Tags: java, android, proguard

I completely understand that `-keep` will preserve class and that `-dontwarn` will just ensure that you don't get a warning. However, I often find myself when including another SDK in my project with this situation - their instructions say add a line:

```
-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
```

When I do that and try to compile with proguard, sure enough my build breaks and I get errors similar to:

```
Warning:com.test.MyClass: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader
```

Obviously as soon as I add `-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.**` the error goes away. But **WHY** is this happening in the first place? `-keep` switch should be enough since it preserves classes. Why must it be doubled with `-dontwarn`?

My guess is that it probably has to do with referencing jars that aren't actually recompiled during the process. So, if somebody knows exact reason why this is going on (sometimes you just need `-keep`, sometimes you need to duplicate it with `-dontwarn`) - I'm all ears.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36435313/244647) might give you a general idea, why it's often necessary to add both `-keep` and `-dontwarn` clauses.

Comment: Thanks @Tomik - that's exactly what I was looking for!